# How to render a div component multiple times with different background color and text in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I have the BoxOne div with yellow pastel color with a p tag inside it that says "Box One". It is a React Component with top: 178px and left: 426px position. Instead of hardcoding a BoxTwo component, how can I use the same BoxOne component to render again but a with a different color and text, at a different position? I'm not planning for conditional rendering, just all appearing at the same time.

Say, orange, with 'Box One Rendered Again' p tag and top: 178px and left: 605px.

There will be five such boxes in a row, all with different color and values. Sharing the codes below:

a. React code for Canvas where BoxOne div is imported:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Canvas.css";
import Workpanel from "../components/Workpanel";
import BoxOne from "../components/BoxOne";

class Canvas extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return(
            <div>
                <Workpanel />
                <div className="canvasContainer">
                    <div className="topicPlanner">
                        <p>Topic Planner</p>
                        <div className="topicVl"></div>
                    </div>
                    <BoxOne /> 
                </div>   
            </div>   
        )
    };
}

export default Canvas;
```

b. React code for BoxOne div

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./BoxOne.css";

function BoxOne() {
    return(
        <div id="boxOneContainer">
            <p className="boxOneText">Box One</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default BoxOne;
```

c. Here's how I want it to look like:

[BoxOne Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nYso.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add props to BoxOne component

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./BoxOne.css";

function BoxOne({style={}, label=''}) {
    return(
        <div id="boxOneContainer" style={style}>
            <p className="boxOneText">{label}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default BoxOne;
```

Then you can use it in the parent component like this:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Canvas.css";
import Workpanel from "../components/Workpanel";
import BoxOne from "../components/BoxOne";

class Canvas extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return(
            <div>
                <Workpanel />
                <div className="canvasContainer">
                    <div className="topicPlanner">
                        <p>Topic Planner</p>
                        <div className="topicVl"></div>
                    </div>
                    <BoxOne text="Box One" /> 
                    <BoxOne text="Box One Rendered Again" style={{color: '#0F0', top: '178px', left: '605px'}} /> 
                </div>   
            </div>   
        )
    };
}

export default Canvas;
```

Altough at this point, you probably want to change the name of the component from `BoxOne` to `Box`...

Since you have five Boxes, it will be cleaner to use an array like this:

```
const boxes = [
  { label: 'box1', style: {} },
  { label: 'box2', style: {left: '100px'} },
  { label: 'box3', style: {left: '200px'} },
  { label: 'box4', style: {left: '300px'} },
  { label: 'box5', style: {left: '400px'} },
];

class Canvas extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return(
            <div>
                <Workpanel />
                <div className="canvasContainer">
                    <div className="topicPlanner">
                        <p>Topic Planner</p>
                        <div className="topicVl"></div>
                    </div>
                   {boxes.map(box => (
                     <BoxOne label={box.label} style={box.style} key={box.label} /> 
                    )}
                </div>   
            </div>   
        )
    };
}

export default Canvas;
```

For more info about props, please read https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Thank you! They didn't work initially but with some minor tweaking in the inline styling they appear as planned!